# TypeError: <unknown> is not a numpy array in cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()

Tags: python, opencv, tracking, opticalflow

I'm trying to make an LK tracker in OpenCV 2.3.1 with python bindings. When I do

```
calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(img1, img2,
                   template_pt, target_pt, status, err, 
                   (win_size_lk, win_size_lk), 0, TERM_CRITERIA_EPS, 
                   (TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 0.03), eig)
```

I'm getting

**TypeError:  is not a numpy array**

where

```
img1, img2 - iplimage
template_pt, target_pt - A List consisting of tuples with two integers eg. [(120,140),(300,400),..]
win_size_lk = 10
eig = 0.001
status = ""
err = None
```

More info about cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK() is given here

http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=opticalflow#cv.CalcOpticalFlowPyrLK

When I set

```
eig = np.array([(0.0,1.0),(1.0,0.0)])
```

It gives me the following error

**TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars**

What could be the problem here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the problem.

```
img1, img2 should be numpy array
template_pt, target_pt should be numpy array
```

So,

```
target_pt, status, track_error = calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(img1, 
                  img2, 
                  template_pt, 
                  target_pt, 
                  winSize=(win_size_lk, win_size_lk), 
                  flags = OPTFLOW_USE_INITIAL_FLOW,
                  criteria = (TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 0.03))
```

works well.